# Get File Headers

Tags: php

I want to get file headers for compare i.e

```
if (file_header == image)
{
  //do something
}
```

but I can't figure out how to do it...
I was looking [mime-content-type](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mime-content-type.php), but it is not working for me... then [finfo-file](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) doenot work because I have only php 5.2 version... So can anyone help me with my problem?

**UPD1** also I can't use [fileinfo()](http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo)

Comment: [PECL fileinfo](http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo) can be installed on 5.2.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I can't use this because of my one princepes

Comment: Where is the file coming from? The filesystem? A remote URL?

Comment: @symcbean from filesystem, and I get path from DB

Comment: Then IT HAS NO HEADERS. You'll have to derive the mimetype from the file extension or it's contents - on most Unix/Linux systems the 'file -i' command will identify the mimetype

Comment: @symcbean ok, but how I can get mimetype?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem with deleting one extra check and all is working now!